# Program hangs when running from a .plist but not from a command script, in OS X El Capitan

Tags: launchd

I'm having a problem running InDesignServer CS6 on a Mac from a .plist.  InDesignServer runs a plugin which the company that I work for wrote.  However, all attempts to trace the problem to the plugin have failed so I have to conclude that the problem is environmental, hence the fact that I am posting here.

If InDesignServer CS6 is run from the script "InDesignServer.command", which is found in the installation directory the plugin runs successfully.

If on the other hand it is run from a .plist file in /Library/LaunchDaemons, it appears to hang at a particular step (which involves opening a file in a directory on the local machine) and become unresponsive.  There is a calling program which sends instructions to the plugin and it just does not get a response from it.

As far as I can tell, the application is running as the same user in each case, i.e. root (when I run it from the .command file I sudo it).  The OS is OS X El Capitan

The only clue I've got to go on is this message, written to the console log when it is running from the .plist but not when it is running from the script "InDesignServer.command".

> 21/07/2016 15:31:25.457 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system) Could not import service from caller: caller = InDesignServer.5018, service = com.adobe.estoolkit-3.8.102432, error = 134: Service cannot load in requested session

I've tried two plists, one running InDesignServer with arguments and one without (there is only one instance running in either case).

Plist 1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.adobe.ids.launchd.1</string>
<key>OnDemand</key>
<false/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Applications/Adobe InDesign CS6 Server/InDesignServer</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Plist 2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
<string>com.adobe.ids.launchd.1</string>
<key>OnDemand</key>
<false/>
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Applications/Adobe InDesign CS6 Server/InDesignServer</string>
    <string>-configuration</string>
    <string>CONFIG1</string>
    <string>-LogToApplicationEventLog</string>
</array>
<key>RunAtLoad</key>
<true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Content of the InDesignServer.command script (which works)

```
#!/bin/bash
script_dirname=`dirname "$0"`

installed_name="$script_dirname/InDesignServer.app/Contents/MacOS
/InDesignServer"
built_name="$script_dirname/../packages/release/InDesignServer.app
/Contents/MacOS/InDesignServer"

if [ -x "$installed_name" ]; then
    "$installed_name" "$@" 
elif [ -x "$built_name" ]; then
    "$built_name" "$@" 
else
    echo Error: InDesign not installed or built correctly ;
fi;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: it would be helpful to post the content of "InDesignServer.command" also.

Comment: It could be the problem with wrong bootstrap, try placing it inside `/Library/LaunchAgents` or `~/Library/LaunchAgents` if it does not need to be run as root.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried copying the .plist to /Library/LaunchAgents and calling launchctl on it from there, but got the same result.

I have added the content of InDesignServer.command to the original post.